# VB.net IsNumeric see if true of fase

Tags: vb.net

I have this in my VB.net application:

```
If IsNumeric("0123456789") Then
    MsgBox("Yes")
End If
```

how can i swap it round so it tells me only if its `False` ?

Comment: With a NOT operator, I guess ?

Comment: Try to not use IsNumeric. Use TryParse also if you just need to test for a number and don't need really a conversion

Comment: it is just a function: `If IsNumeric(myString) = False Then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can use the [Not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx) operator:

```
If Not IsNumeric("012345") Then
     MessageBox.Show("Not Numeric")
End If
```

Just be careful when you use `IsNumeric`, as it may return true when you are not expecting it, take these examples:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TestNumeric("12345")    'Is
    TestNumeric("123e5")    'Is 
    TestNumeric("1.2345")    'Is
    TestNumeric("123EFG")   'Is Not
    TestNumeric("EFG1234")  'Is Not

    TestNumeric("0x05")     'Is Not
    TestNumeric("1,,,234,5")    'Is
    TestNumeric("1,.,2.34,5")    'Is Not

End Sub

Private Sub TestNumeric(Number As String)
    If Not IsNumeric(Number) Then
        MessageBox.Show(Number + " - Not Numeric")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(Number + " - Is Numeric")
    End If
End Sub
```

You also need to know that it uses the thread's culture to determine validity, so while in `EN-US`, this is the case:

```
TestNumeric("1,,,234,5")    'Is
TestNumeric("1...234.5")    'Is Not
```

Switching to `DE`, you get:

```
TestNumeric("1,,,234,5")    'Is Not
TestNumeric("1...234.5")    'Is
```